# unable to install JDK using chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

```
windows_package 'JDK' do
  source 'http://tvmatp236702d:8081/nexus/content/repositories/CSDP/jdk/windows/jdk_windows/1.0.0/jdk_windows-1.0.0.exe'
  options '-ms'
  installer_type :custom
  action :install
end
```

On running the above recipe, jdk is getting downloaded but for installation I am getting this error:

```
**RuntimeError:
Unable to find a Chef::Provider::Package::Windows provider for installer_type 'custom'**
```

Comment: which version of chef are you using ? (and is you .exe file an MSI file in the inner ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:custom` installer type was only added to Chef's core in 12.6. Before that you will need to include the `windows` cookbook.